# Halachic definition of a house for rent

Tags: halacha, money, home-house, rental

House renting services like Airbnb are very popular these days and I've used their services while traveling abroad. Usually, the advertisement requires pictures of the place,  but many times those are photoshopped or taken from a special angle.

Imagine one rents a flat in NY from a Jewish dealer through a phone call without seeing it only agreed on its footage and price.

What conditions in the rented apartment are the sure dealbreakers according to our Halacha?

(IIRC, the Gemmorah in B"B requires the ceiling to be higher than 10 Tfachim - 80-100cm).

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect this is different than any other commerce related rules, which is basically everything follows the local custom?

Comment: @Salmononius2 Do you mean we have nothing on the issue? We rely completely on the surrounding nations?

Comment: This teshuva on reclaiming a rental agent's fee for an apartment rental gone wrong will show you where to look. Interestingly it compares a rental agent to a shadchan! :http://dinonline.org/2019/09/24/reclaiming-the-rental-agents-fee-when-the-apartment-becomes-unlivable/

Comment: @AlBerko no one said anything about surrounding nations